# Can't boot either ubuntu or windows 8

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub, ubuntu-12.04

- I have dual boot installation of windows 8 and ubuntu.
- "Sometimes" when I start my laptop, it gets stuck on very first
  screen (displaying Samsung, Intel, F2 to setup etc). But after a
  couple of restart it starts working. I have no idea what the problem
  could be.
- Generally it shows the ubuntu boot screen asking if I want to boot
  ubuntu or windows 8 as it should.
- And sometimes I get a Grub error after the "Samsung" screen, saying
  no such partition.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a flaky hard disk? I think you probably have some kind of hardware problem. If you 
have any important data, your first step should be to backup.